# Getting Task not Serializable error on trying to create Decision Tree using Spark with Scala while executing in my local machine

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pipeline, decision-tree

I am trying to create Fraud Transaction Detector using spark with scala. My code works fine with normal Spark logic. However when I try the solution using decision tree approach I get task not Serializable error. From my understanding I get this error when I try fitting my training data into pipeline. I tried a few solutions like extending to Serializable, converting my indexed data back to string etc. but none of them worked.

Can someone please help in understanding what I am doing wrong

Below is my code

```
     package com.vinspark.frauddetection


     object FraudDet_ML extends Serializable{

     def main(args:Array[String]){

     Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

     val spark=SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("FraudDetection")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","file:///C:/temp")
      .getOrCreate()

     import spark.sqlContext.implicits._


     var df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", 
     "DROPMALFORMED").option("inferSchema", "true").load("../PS_20174392719_1491204439457_log.csv")
 
     df= df.withColumn("orgDiff", col("newbalanceOrig") - 
      col("oldbalanceOrg")).withColumn("destDiff", 
      col("newbalanceDest") - col("oldbalanceDest"))

 
     df=   df.withColumn("label",
       when((col("oldbalanceOrg") <=56900 && col("type")=="TRANSFER" && col("newbalanceDest") <= 105)
       ||(col("oldbalanceOrg") >56900 && col("newbalanceOrig")<=12)
       ||(col("oldbalanceOrg") >56900 && col("newbalanceOrig")>12 && col("amount")>1160000),
     1)
     .otherwise(0) 
     )

     df.createOrReplaceTempView("transaction")

 
     val indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("type").setOutputCol("typeIndexed")   
     println("indexer created")
 
     val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
      .setInputCol("label")
      .setOutputCol("indexedLabel").fit(df)

     val splitDataSet: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] 
       =df.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), 12345L)
     val trainDataFrame = splitDataSet(0)val testDataFrame = splitDataSet(1)
     val train = splitDataSet(0)
     val test = splitDataSet(1)
     println("train: "+train.count()+" test: "+test.count())
 
     val va = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("typeIndexed", "amount", "oldbalanceOrg", 
      "newbalanceOrig", "oldbalanceDest", "newbalanceDest", "orgDiff", 
      "destDiff")).setOutputCol("features")
      
     println("vector assembler created")    
     val dt = new DecisionTreeClassifier()
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setFeaturesCol("features").setSeed(54321).setMaxDepth(5)

      println("decision tree created")

      val labelConverter = new IndexToString()
        .setInputCol("prediction")
        .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
        .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels)

       val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(indexer,labelIndexer, va, dt))  
       println("pipeline created")   
       val pipeConst=pipeline  
       val model = pipeConst.fit(train)  
       val model1 = model  
       println("model created")
       val prediction=model1.transform(test)
       println("indexer created")
       prediction.collect().foreach(println)
      }
      }
```

Comment: indexer created
train: 5089770 test: 1272850
vector assembler created
decision tree created
pipeline created
20/11/18 09:52:04 ERROR Instrumentation: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:416)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:406)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2356)

Comment: Can you include a training sample to your question?

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 the training set looks something like tthis initially but for my logic to work I had to add two more columns at run time i.e. Sapmple, Origin Difference(orgDiff) and Destination Difference(destDiff)

Comment: step type amount nameOrig oldbalanceOrg newbalanceOrig nameDest oldbalanceDest newbalanceDest isFraud isFlaggedFraud
1 PAYMENT 9839.64 C1231006815 170136 160296.36 M1979787155 0 0 0 0
1 PAYMENT 1864.28 C1666544295 21249 19384.72 M2044282225 0 0 0 0
1 TRANSFER 181 C1305486145 181 0 C553264065 0 0 1 0

Comment: Your code seems to work ok, although I would work with immutable df representations intead of using var, with Spark 2.4.5 and Scala 2.12.10. Which version of Spark and Scala are you using?

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 my spark version is 3.0.0 and Scala version is 2.12.0.  Also I tried changing var to val for DF but no luck

Comment: val df2=spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").option("inferSchema", "true").load("../PS_20174392719_1491204439457_log.csv")
val df1= df2.withColumn("orgDiff", col("newbalanceOrig") - col("oldbalanceOrg")).withColumn("destDiff", col("newbalanceDest") - col("oldbalanceDest"))
val df=df1.withColumn("label"when((col("oldbalanceOrg<=56900&&col("type")=="TRANSFER"&&col("newbalanceDest") <= 105)||(col("oldbalanceOrg") >56900 && col("newbalanceOrig")<=12)||(col("oldbalanceOrg") >56900 && col("newbalanceOrig")>12 &&col("amount")>1160000),1).otherwise(0) )